# Is there a XML builder/parser that will fill java model classes with data?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, builder

I've been searching on stackoverflow and google for about a 20 minutes, and could find a solution to this. I could write my own XSD generator and then XML builder, but I can't believe there is not some framework/library that can do that.

Maybe you know about some...

For better understanding I've made up these files:

**XML:**

```
<root>
    <spritesheets>
        <spritesheet id="1" spritecount="16" spriteWidth="32" spriteHeight="32" source="spritesheets/sprites_grass.png" />
        <spritesheet id="2" spritecount="24" spriteWidth="64" spriteHeight="64" source="spritesheets/sprites_trees.png" />
        <spritesheet id="3" spritecount="24" spriteWidth="64" spriteHeight="64" source="spritesheets/sprites_bigtrees.png" />
        <spritesheet id="4" spritecount="12" spriteWidth="128" spriteHeight="128" source="spritesheets/sprites_mothertree.png" />
    </spritesheets>

    <animations>
        <animation id="1" name="Grass Moving 1" spritesheet_id="1" from="1" to="8" period="200" />
        <animation id="2" name="Grass Moving 2" spritesheet_id="1" from="9" to="16" period="200" />
        <animation id="3" name="Grass Moving Slowly 1" spritesheet_id="1" from="1" to="8" period="350" />
        <animation id="4" name="Grass Moving Slowly 2" spritesheet_id="1" from="9" to="16" period="350" />
        <animation id="5" name="Tree 1" spritesheet_id="2" from="1" to="12" period="200" />
        <animation id="6" name="Tree 2" spritesheet_id="2" from="13" to="24" period="200" />
        <animation id="7" name="Big Tree 1" spritesheet_id="3" from="1" to="12" period="200" />
        <animation id="8" name="Big Tree 2" spritesheet_id="3" from="13" to="24" period="200" />
        <animation id="9" name="Mother Tree" spritesheet_id="4" from="1" to="24" period="250" />
    </animations>

    <objects>
        <walkable id="1" name="Jungle Grass 1" width="1" height="1" animation_id="1" />
        <walkable id="2" name="Jungle Grass 2" width="1" height="1" animation_id="2" />
        <walkable id="3" name="Jungle Grass 3" width="1" height="1" animation_id="3" />
        <walkable id="4" name="Jungle Grass 4" width="1" height="1" animation_id="4" />
        <placeable id="5" name="Tree 1" width="1" height="1" animation_id="5" />
        <placeable id="6" name="Tree 2" width="1" height="1" animation_id="6" />
        <placeable id="7" name="Big Tree 1" width="2" height="2" animation_id="7" />
        <placeable id="8" name="Big Tree 2" width="2" height="2" animation_id="8" />
        <placeable id="9" name="Mother Tree" width="3" height="3" animation_id="9" />
        <monster... />
    </objects>

    <locations>
        <location id="1" name="Jungle" width="500" height="500">
            <object object_ref_id="1" posX="0" posY="0" />
            <object object_ref_id="1" posX="0" posY="1" />
            <object object_ref_id="2" posX="0" posY="2" />
            <object object_ref_id="4" posX="0" posY="3" />
            ...
            <object object_ref_id="9" posX="250" posY="250" />
            ...
            <object object_ref_id="3" posX="500" posY="499" />
            <object object_ref_id="3" posX="500" posY="500" />
        </location>
    </locations>
</root>
```

**Java classes:**

**Root:**

```
public class Root {
    List<Spritesheet> spritesheets;
    List<Animation> animations;
    List<Object> objects;
    List<Location> locations;
}
```

**Spritesheet:**

```
public class Spritesheet {
    int id;
    int spritecount;
    int spriteWidth;
    int spriteHeight;
    String source;
}
```

**Animation:**

```
public class Animation {
    int id;
    String name;
    int spritesheet_id;
    int from;
    int to;
    int period;
}
```

**Object:**

```
public abstract class Object {
    int id;
    String name;
    int width;
    int height;
    int animation_id;
}
```

**Walkable:**

```
public class Walkable extends Object {

}
```

**Placeable:**

```
public class Placeable extends Object {

}
```

**Location:**

```
public class Location {
    List<Object> objects;
    int id;
    String name;
    int width;
    int height;
}
```

How to simply convert the XML into java classes? XSD validation is not needed, but it would be nice in the future.

Comment: JaxB, Jackson and many more

Comment: I am not sure if Jackson is related to this issue, but JaxB might work. It is kind of overkill for me since its not trivial to use it, but I'll look into it.

Comment: i am also interested in such a tool

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial tools that allows to do this inside their tools. For instance,  I've used Tibco ActiveMatrix Designer that allows you to map xml files (based on a xsd file)into a Java instance objects. In fact, at design time, you can drag and drop fields from the xml to the java objects. You can then use this objects inside activities that execute java code.
Maybe it won't work for you since you hace to deploy the ear generated into his own administrator server.
I suppose there are other solutions like that.